# Searching for words in a corpus with R

Tags: r, full-text-search, cpu-word, corpus

I am trying to search for strings of words in a corpus using R. Are disjunctive statements allowed in grep, e.g., grep("a" or "b" or "c"...)? If so, once I have that subcorpus, how do I then refine it further to contain only those examples with at least two tokens of the original condition?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the vertical bar `|` works as an or-operator in `grep`. You can look up regular expressions in R by running `?regex`.

So, to give an example:

```
grep("ape|bass|cat", c("monkey", "bass", "catfish"))
[1] 2 3
```

Also confer the documentation of `grep`, `grepl`, and that family of functions.
The `stringr` package provide additional tools for handling text.